# How to order a query set based on custom list

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a model

```
Class Foo(Model):
    name = models.charfield(max_length=100)
    fk = models.foreignkey('SomeModel')
    datetime = models.datetimefield()
```

Now I want this Foo to be filtered or ordered by customized name i.e. I have a list of names and I want it to be  ordered by that.

list = ('Ground', 'Floor', 'Basement'). i.e. all Foo objects with the name containing ground will come first, then all foo objects containing floor 2nd and then all objects containing basement.

I want something like this. This is not right, but I want something similar.

```
some_list = ('Ground', 'Floor', 'Basement')
Foo.objects.filter(fk=some).order_by(name__icontains=some_list)
```

Please comment if the question is not clear.

Comment: need more information, what kind of sorting you are looking for.

Comment: Say... Sort the display of floors according to their name.

Comment: So, you mean sorting the data on the template ?

Comment: Please read the edited question

Answer (score 0):

Given this model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_len=255)
```

You'll sort it using [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by):

```
MyModel.objects.all().order_by('name')
```

You can also set the default ordering of the object by changing [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) inside the `Meta` class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_len=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name', '-date_created']
```

This will first sort by `name` ascending and then on `date_created` descending (given that you have fields named `name` and `date_created`)

Comment: If you plan on developing with Django, you should learn to use the documentation. [First hit on Google](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) searching for `django sort` is the specific place in the docs where this is mentioned.